# Most efficient way to compare two near identical CSV's in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm, csv, search

I have two CSV's, each with about 1M lines, n number of columns, with identical columns. I want the most efficient way to compare the two files to find where any difference may lie. I would prefer to parse this data with Python rather than use any excel-related tools.

Comment: Please add sample code and few lines from the input file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using pandas?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
df = df.append(pd.read_csv('file2.csv'), ignore_index=True)

# array indicating which rows are duplicated
df[df.duplicated()]

# dataframe with only unique rows
df[~df.duplicated()]

# dataframe with only duplicate rows
df[df.duplicated()]

# number of duplicate rows present
df.duplicated().sum()
```

Comment: Does pandas automatically handle strings with capital characters, or will I need to handle that first? e.g. 'John' vs 'john'.

Comment: It handles it automatically. It does not see 'John' as equal to 'john'. If that's a problem, you can use `df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].str.lower()` to turn all string values lowercase.

Comment: This is awesome; thank you! I will do some research into the pandas library!

Answer (score 1):

An efficient way would be to read each line from the first file(with less number of lines) and save in an object like Set or Dictionary, where you can access using O(1) complexity.

And then read lines from the second file and check if it exists in the Set or not.

Comment: Thank you for this; I was actually looking for an actual solution, but I understand this is still a correct answer on how I would make it efficient, so I wanted to upvote and respond. Thank you!